# PHP - Notice: Undefined index: and not displaying data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

this is code of search.php. i want to take search by date from the input box as below.

```
<form action="visitor-print.php">
    <div class="col-sm-3 text-center"><h3>Date</h3>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="dat" placeholder="Enter Date">
        <p class="help-block">Month Format 1,2,3,....29,30..</p>
        <button class="btn btn-default"><span>Submit</span></button>
    </div>
   </form>
```

this is my visitor-print.php code where i get undefined index error on dat (which is from the other page)

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
mysql_select_db('visitor_list');
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM list1 WHERE d1 = '". $_POST["dat"] . "' ";

$retval = mysql_query(  $sql,$conn ) or die("Error: ".mysql_error($conn));

?>
 <div class="container">  
            <h3 class="text-center">User Feed-Back Details</h3><br /> 
            <div class="table-responsive" id="employee_table">  
                 <table class="table table-bordered">  
                      <tr>  
                           <th width="10%">Visitor Name</th>    
                           <th width="10%">Address</th>  
                           <th width="10%">Area to Visit</th>  
                           <th width="10%">Phone No.</th> 
                           <th width="20%">Want to meet with </th> 
                           <th width="50%">Purpose of meeting</th>  
                      </tr>  
                      <?php   
                      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval,MYSQLI_BOTH))  
                      {  
                      ?>  
                      <tr>  
                           <td><?php echo $row['nm']; ?></td>  
                           <td><?php echo $row['add1']; ?></td>  
                           <td><?php echo $row['area_vis']; ?></td>  
                           <td><?php echo $row['y1']; ?></td> 
                           <td><?php echo $row['app_ty']; ?></td>
                           <td><?php echo $row['no_per']; ?></td> 
                      </tr>  
                      <?php                           
                      }  
                      ?>  
                 </table>  
            </div>  
            <div align="center">  
                 <button name="create_excel" id="create_excel" class="btn btn-success">Create Excel File</button>  
            </div>  
       </div>
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
       <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
    <script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){  
 $('#create_excel').click(function(){  
       var excel_data = $('#employee_table').html();  
       var page = "excel.php?data=" + excel_data;  
       window.location = page;  
  });  
});  
</script>
```

Problem:
Notice: Undefined index: dat in D:\wamp\www\radissun visitor\visitor-print.php on line 12
and is not showing data from mysql

Comment: MISSING FORM SUBMIT <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" NAME="SUBMIT" VALUE="SUBMIT" >

Comment: <button TYPE="SUBMIT" class="btn btn-default"><span>Submit</span></button>

Comment: Shouldn't `mysql_query(  $sql,$conn )` be `mysql_query($sql)` You have already connected so no need to add the connection string into the query...

Comment: do not use mysql_ functions. cause they are **deprecated** since php 5.5.0

Comment: I also agree with Blueblazer, look at using mysqli.

Answer (score 0):

The answer you are looking for: You are using $_POST - which is just for forms which have method="post". Default method is GET - so your variables are $_GET[]. You can either set the method parameter in the html to POST, or you change your PHP code to GET.

But I must point out, that your code is not usable for productive environments, as it is vulnerable to SQL Injection. See http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp

Comment: Thank you everyone for the replies
all your answers had helped me very much

Answer (score 0):

MISSING METHOD ON FORM `METHOD="POST"`

`NOTE:` IF YOU USE `METHOD="POST"` YOU CAN GET VALUE BY $_POST['dat']; IF YOUR NOT USING METHOD ATTRIBUTE .FORM JUST SUBMITED AS GET METHOD YOU CAN GET BY $_GET['dat'];

```
<form action="visitor-print.php" METHOD="POST" >
```

MISSING FORM SUBMIT

```
<INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" NAME="SUBMIT" VALUE="SUBMIT" >
```

(OR)

ADD `TYPE="SUBMIT"` TO BUTTON

```
<button TYPE="SUBMIT" class="btn btn-default"><span>Submit</span></button>
```

Comment: Buttons are of type "submit" by default.